# Getting a "Value for <column> in table <table> is DBNull" error

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on a WCF service, in which I'm trying to load data from one data table passed to the method, into another data table from the local database (in this case, the "local" database is a SQL Server database on a Windows 2003 Server).  When I do I get the following error message:

"The value for column 'VocNeedDesc' in table 'ASIVocationalNeeds' is DBNull."

This actually is OK, because column VocNeedDesc in table ASIVocationalNeeds allows nulls.  Originally I just assigned the value of VocNeedDesc from the passed table to the local table, but I got that error.  So next I changed my code to check the value of VocNeedDesc to see if it was null, and if so I assigned string.Empty to the value, otherwise I assigned the passed value, but I still get the error message.  I'm stumped; don't know why I'm getting this error.  Here's the relevant code segment:

```
localEmploy.ASIVocationalNeeds.Rows.Add(clientNumber,
    caseNumber,
    0,
    EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedType,
    (EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc == null ? string.Empty : EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DBNull check apply on cell value not for whole columns

So Try this

```
EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds.Rows[i]["VocNeedDesc"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc));
```

if you are using typeDatset 
you can check null values as

```
((ASIVocationalNeedsRow)EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds.Rows[i]).isVocNeedDescnull() ? string.Empty : EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc));
```

Comment: I am using a typed dataset, and so I thought I'd give your suggestion a try.  I am now using the IsVocNeedDescNull() method on the EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds data table.  In testing it worked!  However, when I compiled it and put it on the server, I still got the, "... value for column 'VocNeedDesc' in table 'ASIVocationalNeeds' is DBBull." error message.  Why does running as a WCF service on a Windows 2003 R2 server make a difference?

Comment: Never mind. I found that in a different conditional I made the same assignment, pulling from EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc, as I shouldn't have been.  Only 15 lines above the code I posted. Argh!  How'd I miss that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing it with [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)?

Code may look-like

```
EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : EmploymentDataSet.ASIVocationalNeeds[i].VocNeedDesc));
```

Comment: No, I haven't.  I just tried it and I got a warning that said, "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'".  However, it does give me an idea, I'll try using the string.IsNullOrEmpty() method.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the string.IsNullOrEmpty() method call didn't work.