# The value for column X in table Y is DBNull

Tags: c#, dataset

I Work in windows form by visual studio 2015 and l creat dataset by design and I added some columns by design. One of this  columns from type Datetime and l set proparties :
AllowDBNull=true 
Default value =.
 When  I run project show this exception " The value for column X in table Y is DBNull"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a "Value for <column> in table <table> is DBNull" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196092/getting-a-value-for-column-in-table-table-is-dbnull-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DBNull.Value instead and empty value. Anyway, a code snippet could be very useful here for a better answer.